# Simple animation using Thread.sleep() in ActionListener

Tags: java, graphics, repaint, japplet, thread-sleep

I'm having trouble with this code I am using to create a roulette wheel. The goal is to spin the wheel when I click the "SPIN!" button. I have done this by creating a for loop that should change the status of the wheel from true to false, which changes the orientation. This, when done fast enough, should create the illusion of movement.

**THE PROBLEM I AM HAVING**: is that my wheel is only repainting after the whole for loop is done, despite my placement of the repaint(). So, it only spins one tick.

Here is some sample code of my ActionListener:

```
public class spinListener implements ActionListener
{
    RouletteWheel wheel;
    int countEnd = (int)(Math.random()+25*2);
    public spinListener(RouletteWheel w)
    {
        wheel = w;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <countEnd; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (wheel.getStatus() == true)
                {
                    wheel.setStatus(false);
                    repaint();
                }
                if (wheel.getStatus() == false)
                {
                    wheel.setStatus(true);
                    repaint();
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(WheelBuilder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I figured out the problem. Here are the changes I made for anyone having a similar problem.

```
public class spinListener implements ActionListener
{
    Timer tm = new Timer(100, this);
    int count = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        tm.start();
        changeWheel();
    }
    public void changeWheel()
    {
        int countEnd = (int)(Math.random()+20*2);
        if (count < countEnd)
        {
            wheel.setStatus(!wheel.getStatus());
            repaint();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swing is a single threaded environment, anything that blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, will prevent it from been able to process new events, including, paint events.

The use of `Thread.sleep` within the `actionPerformed` method is blocking the EDT, preventing it from processing new events, including paint events, until the `actionPerformed` method is exited.

You should use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: I tried using a timer in an earlier attempt, but I could not figure out how to trigger the animation with a button when using a Timer. Any input?

Comment: `Timer#start` would be my first guess

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it figured out. Had to create another separate method that changed the wheel's graphics, then use the timer in the Action Listener class.