# Delay between lines in Java

Tags: java, swing, delay, wait

I'm creating a card game in Java and would like to portray the appearance of dealing. I have JLabels created and am making them visible by using .setVisible(true) and would like to put a delay between each card being visible.
I've tried using wait() and Thread.sleep() but neither worked. wait() gave me errors and Thread.sleep just paused the entire program, not just each appearance. (This code runs when a "Next" button is pressed so it is in the actionPerformed method)

Note: I am a beginner.. please keep it simple :)

```
else if(eventName.equals("Next"))
  {
     rules.setVisible(false);
     next.setVisible(false);
     inst.setVisible(false);
     cardDeck.setVisible(true);
     discard.setVisible(true);
     tot.setVisible(true);
     specialCards.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     userCard1.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     compCard1.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     userCard2.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     compCard2.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     userCard3.setVisible(true);
     // delay here
     compCard3.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Comment: you have to animate each view

Comment: is this eventually being executed on the event thread? e.g. in an ActionListener like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23924373/85421)

Comment: It's not in an action listener, but it's in the actionPerformed method

Comment: and that is not used as the `actionPerformed` defined in the `ActionListener` interface???

Comment: yes actually.. ignore the last comment oops

Comment: well, you should not use sleep (block) on the Event Dispatch Thread - this blocks the GUI, that is, no updates... try a `SwingWorker` (search on StackOverflow, it's a well known problem... but it's to late for me to search it now, sorry)

Comment: and almost all Swing classes should have a link to the Swing's Threading Policy - kind of good to learn if working with Swing

Comment: Re, "It's not in an action listener, but it's in the actionPerformed method"

Nothing will change on the screen, and your program will be unable to respond to any user input until that actionPerformed() handler returns.

Do what @MichaelBeer said instead: Use a Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to have the labels being shown after some time.
You will see in the docs that using them is really straight forward.

You could also just insert code that pauses your app for a certain amount of time like [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)), but this would render your app entirely unresponsive as long as the app waits.

Simple example:

```
package testTimer;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest extends JFrame {

    // These labels will be shown after some delay
    JLabel l1 = null;
    JLabel l2 = null;

    public TimerTest() {

        Container cpane = getContentPane();
        cpane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cpane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Timer Test");
        l.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        cpane.add(l);
        l.setVisible(true);
        l1 = new JLabel("1");
        l2 = new JLabel("2");
        cpane.add(l1);
        l1.setVisible(false);
        cpane.add(l2);
        l2.setVisible(false);

        // Now prepare two timers, one for each label
        int delayForL1Millis = 1000;
        Timer t1 = new Timer(delayForL1Millis, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                l1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        t1.setRepeats(false);

        int delayForL2Millis = 2000;
        Timer t2 = new Timer(delayForL2Millis, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                l2.setVisible(true);
            };
        });
        t2.setRepeats(false);

        // And start them
        t1.start();
        t1 = null;
        t2.start();
        t2 = null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        TimerTest timertest = new TimerTest();
        timertest.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't figure out how to work it

Comment: I added an example on how to use the timers to show labels delayed...